# The state monad and learnyouahaskell.com

Tags: haskell, monads

I was reading [Learn You a Haskell's guide on the state monad](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#state), but I had trouble understanding it since the stack example couldn't compile. In the guide, he used the following piece of code:

```
import Control.Monad.State  

type Stack = [Int]

pop :: State Stack Int  
pop = State $ \(x:xs) -> (x,xs)  

push :: Int -> State Stack ()  
push a = State $ \xs -> ((),a:xs)
```

While I understand what it's supposed to do, it won't compile. I have no idea why. The error message is:

```
Stack.hs:6:7: Not in scope: data constructor `State'

Stack.hs:9:10: Not in scope: data constructor `State'
```

This makes no sense to me, since "State" is, to my knowledge, in fact a data constructor, defined as

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a,s) }
```

Is the guide "wrong", and if so, how do I fix it?

Comment: `Control.Monad.State` doesn't export the `State` constructor, use `state` (with lower-case `s`).

Comment: @Vitus Nice, I didn't know [that function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#v:state) was exported. I think you should write it as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @Vitus: that's odd then, because his code actually compiles and runs well on my GHCI 6.12.3 on windows.

Comment: @Undreren: which compiler/version are you using? Maybe this is your issue.

Comment: @Riccardo: If you use older version of the library, yes. But newest versions don't define `newtype State`. edit: I'm not sure about this actually, better check with someone who's been around for some time.

Comment: @Vitus: good to know, thanks. You should include this info in your answer I think, since it is exactly the explanation for the compilation error he's experiencing.

Comment: @Riccardo `State` was deprecated in favor of `StateT`. Since the `State` monad can be defined as `StateT` on the `Identity` monad, and so it's now a type synonym and there's no `State` data constructor.

Comment: ok, so it's just because learnyouahaskell is old? :)

Comment: @Undreren: I'd say a bit outdated, but certainly not "old". :D

Comment: Fair, if this is the only problematic difference, then fine :) States just seem like a really useful tool, and as such I wanted to understand it :)

Comment: In my copy of LYAH, it already says "Much like `Control.Monad.Writer`, `Control.Monad.State` doesn't export its value constructor. If you want to take a stateful computation, use the `state` function, which does the same thing that the `State` constructor would do." – Funny that's not present in the online version yet.

Comment: I have already sent an email to him regarding this :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, you ought to use `state` instead of `State`.

---

The problem is that `State` is not standalone data type (or rather `newtype`), but it is the `StateT` transformer applied to `Identity` monad. Actually, it's defined as

```
type State s = StateT s Indentity
```

and because it's just `type` synonym, it cannot have `State` constructor. That's why `Control.Monad.State` uses `state`.

Comment: This no longer works. Does anyone know of the proper syntax?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer already mentions to use the `state` function from `Control.Monad.State` rather than the `State` type. However, if you simply try the accepted answer in `ghci` with the associated `mtl` package loaded, it will still fail:

```
Prelude Control.Monad.State> push a = state $ \xs -> ((), a:xs)

<interactive>:5:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: MonadState [a] m
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        push :: forall a (m :: * -> *). MonadState [a] m => a -> m ()
```

To resolve this, there are two options here:

1. Either specify the type signature for the function (which you should anyways).
2. Add the `FlexibleContexts` compiler extension, as mentioned in the error.

We can specify the type signature:

```hs
module LearnYouAHaskell where

import Control.Monad.State as State

push :: Int -> State.State [Int] ()
push a = State.state $ \xs -> ((), a:xs)
```

The above compiles fine and functions as expected.

Or we can add the language extension so it can infer the function type.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
module LearnYouAHaskell where

import Control.Monad.State as State

push a = State.state $ \xs -> ((), a:xs)
```

Which will also work fine.